# Installing Chromium OS on newly built computer

Tags: computer-building, google-chrome-os

I am wondering if I can install Chromium OS on my computer that I have just built that currently has no operating system yet. So basically, I'm wondering if Chromium OS can be installed on a computer as the first operating system.
 Can anybody point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you have another computer to create the required USB image ...

Comment: [Quick Start Guide - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/quick-start-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Use neverware (download - https://www.neverware.com/) Neverware is a chrome os built for computers that aren't chromebooks. I would suggest using this.